# Gaussian Copula: Transformation to Normality and Interpretation of Copula Correlation

Tags: distributions, correlation, normal-distribution, copula

Assume we have the marginal distributions for two variables: Security1_Price and Security2_Price. These two distributions are mapped to standard normal distributions U1 and U2. **How exactly does this transformation to normality work?**

If we were to assume that the copula correlation between U1 and U2 is 0.4. **What exactly does this last assumption mean and how is it related to the transformation to normality? How do we get an intuitive feel for what this correlation number between two distributions means?**

Comment: What it means depends very much on those initial transformations to normality.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out, whuber. I will expand my question to ask about the transformation to normality as well.

Comment: Re the edit: the answer to "how does this transformation to normality work" is called the ["probability integral transform."](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=probability+integral+transform)